# Which hook is invoked after an endpoint creates a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, services

I am using Services 7.3x with Drupal 7. I have setup an endpoint that creates nodes. After a node is created by the endpoint, I would like to retrieve some data from the new node and update a third-party database.

I understand that the Services resource uses drupal_form_submit to create the node. I attempted to add a custom submit to the hook_form_alter but that did not get called. I also attempted to use hook_node_insert. But that also did not get called.

What hook can I call after the node is inserted?